# Create a command line pack for Windows Server with couple of actions to perform

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, windows-server-2012

Would like to create a pack for windows 2008 Server (hopefully compatible with Windows 2003 Server). Basically a windows powershell script which should perform below tasks in command line. Idea is to provide this script to a Windows Sys Admin to execute this script on target windows server.

1. Create a windows Inbound Firewall rule to allow port 22 from any host.
2. Create a bunch of directories and set ownership to a service account (e.g username = deployuser from Active Directory) by reading a comma separated property value “directoryToCreate” (e.g directoryToCreate=”c:/temp,c:/temp/stage,c:/temp/cache,c:/temp/src”
3. Execute an EXE which will create a windows service
4. Verify Step 3 windows service has been created and STARTED and RUNNING fine.
   5  Final report showing on all above activities.
     e.g directories created successfully
           Inbound Rule created successfully
           Exe execution and Windows Service verified successfully

Since I have to perform this pack on 30+ Servers, Any suggestion/advise on the best practice please?
Is powershell good enough?
Can I create and EXE Installer on top of powershell?
etc

Thanks in advance

Comment: The tasks seem straightforward in the sense that there are many existing solutions/answers for each of the steps. However the question as a whole is too broad/[off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: It seems that the core of this question lays in _how to deploy that on 30+ servers_. This would better fit to ServerFault.

Comment: Sorry, what is the suggestion here?  :)